# How to create object of ActionEvent class in java?

Tags: java

Anyone please told me How to create object of **ActionEvent** class in *java* ?? and how to use method of the **ActionEvent** Class

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? You need be more descriptive about the problem you're facing and also share your attempt for us to be able to help you better!

Comment: `ActionEvent e = ActionEvent(source, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "command");` is the answer. But I'm not sure what the question was. You should state *clearly* what you are going to do with this event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do be more descriptive on what you are trying to do.

But here is a sample of two different types of using an ActionEvent

If you are using JComponents and you want to add it to a button and maybe other things i have clue just do

```
component.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
   //import the ActionListener and then you will be prompted to add an actionPerformed method
});
```

If you want to make a class of it just do something like this.

```
private class Listener1 implements ActionListener
{
 //again it will ask that you import it if not already imported and add the method actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) which is where you will put your code
}
```

Then somewhere in your code do

```
object.addActionListener(new Listener1());
```

No clue what you are asking for so i hope some of the above code helps